# Recovering xampp mysql db

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have accident drop one of xampp mysql db, is anyway to recover it. I don't have backup. I have check the mysql/data folder and it's disappear.

Answer (score 0):

If it's physically gone, the only way you are going to revert it is by using data recovery software. The less writes you've done to your disk since deleting the files, the better chance you have for recovery.